# I can't set up a Neo4j cluster

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4j server that works fine but, when I tried to set up a cluster I can't just figure out why it does not work.

In order to make the cluster work, it seems I just need to uncoment the following lines:

```
ha.server_id = 3
ha.initial_hosts =192.168.1.93:5001,192.168.1.91:5001
dbms.mode=HA
```

but when I do so, I got an error in the logs file about the db load.

This is my neo4j.conf file

```
#*****************************************************************
# Neo4j configuration
#*****************************************************************

# The name of the database to mount
dbms.active_database=graph.db

# Paths of directories in the installation.
dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data
dbms.directories.plugins=/var/lib/neo4j/plugins
#dbms.directories.certificates=certificates

# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or uncomment it to
# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the `LOAD CSV`
# section of the manual for details.
dbms.directories.import=import

# Whether requests to Neo4j are authenticated.
# To disable authentication, uncomment this line
#dbms.security.auth_enabled=false

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
#dbms.allow_format_migration=true

# The amount of memory to use for mapping the store files, in bytes (or
# kilobytes with the 'k' suffix, megabytes with 'm' and gigabytes with 'g').
# If Neo4j is running on a dedicated server, then it is generally recommended
# to leave about 2-4 gigabytes for the operating system, give the JVM enough
# heap to hold all your transaction state and query context, and then leave the
# rest for the page cache.
# The default page cache memory assumes the machine is dedicated to running
# Neo4j, and is heuristically set to 50% of RAM minus the max Java heap size.
#dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g
# Enable online backups to be taken from this database.
#dbms.backup.enabled=true

# To allow remote backups, uncomment this line:
#dbms.backup.address=0.0.0.0:6362

#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.type=BOLT
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
# To have Bolt accept non-local connections, uncomment this line
# dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687

# HTTP Connector
dbms.connector.http.type=HTTP
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.encryption=NONE
# To have HTTP accept non-local connections, uncomment this line
dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474

# HTTPS Connector
dbms.connector.https.type=HTTP
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.encryption=TLS
dbms.connector.https.address=localhost:7473

# Number of Neo4j worker threads.
#dbms.threads.worker_count=

#*****************************************************************
# HA configuration
#*****************************************************************

# Uncomment and specify these lines for running Neo4j in High Availability mode.
# See the High availability setup tutorial for more details on these settings
# http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#tutorials

# Database mode
# Allowed values:
# HA - High Availability
# SINGLE - Single mode, default.
# To run in High Availability mode uncomment this line:
#dbms.mode=HA

# ha.server_id is the number of each instance in the HA cluster. It should be
# an integer (e.g. 1), and should be unique for each cluster instance.
ha.server_id=5

# ha.initial_hosts is a comma-separated list (without spaces) of the host:port
# where the ha.host.coordination of all instances will be listening. Typically
# this will be the same for all cluster instances.
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.1.93:5001,192.168.1.91:5001

# IP and port for this instance to listen on, for communicating cluster status
# information iwth other instances (also see ha.initial_hosts). The IP
# must be the configured IP address for one of the local interfaces.
ha.host.coordination=127.0.0.1:5001

# IP and port for this instance to listen on, for communicating transaction
# data with other instances (also see ha.initial_hosts). The IP
# must be the configured IP address for one of the local interfaces.
ha.host.data=127.0.0.1:6001

ha.pull_interval=10

# Amount of slaves the master will try to push a transaction to upon commit
# (default is 1). The master will optimistically continue and not fail the
# transaction even if it fails to reach the push factor. Setting this to 0 will
# increase write performance when writing through master but could potentially
# lead to branched data (or loss of transaction) if the master goes down.
#ha.tx_push_factor=1

# Strategy the master will use when pushing data to slaves (if the push factor
# is greater than 0). There are three options available "fixed_ascending" (default),
# "fixed_descending" or "round_robin". Fixed strategies will start by pushing to
# slaves ordered by server id (accordingly with qualifier) and are useful when
# planning for a stable fail-over based on ids.
#ha.tx_push_strategy=fixed_ascending

# Policy for how to handle branched data.
#ha.branched_data_policy=keep_all

# How often heartbeat messages should be sent. Defaults to ha.default_timeout.
#ha.heartbeat_interval=5s

# Timeout for heartbeats between cluster members. Should be at least twice that of ha.heartbeat_interval.
#ha.heartbeat_timeout=11s

# If you are using a load-balancer that doesn't support HTTP Auth, you may need to turn off authentication for the
# HA HTTP status endpoint by uncommenting the following line.
#dbms.security.ha_status_auth_enabled=false

# Whether this instance should only participate as slave in cluster. If set to
# true, it will never be elected as master.
#ha.slave_only=false
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you get an error on startup, the least you could do is quote it here, otherwise there's not much anyone can do about it.

Regarding your configuration, there's at least one mistake: to participate in a cluster with other hosts using IP addresses such as 192.168.1.93 and 192.168.1.91, you need to set up this host to communicate on the same network, **not on loopback** (i.e. 127.0.0.1) which other hosts cannot connect to.

If this host has e.g. 192.168.1.93, that's what you need to use:

```
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.1.93:5001,192.168.1.91:5001
ha.host.coordination=192.168.1.93:5001
ha.host.data=192.168.1.93:6001
```

However, if your host has 192.168.1.92, you need to add it to `ha.initial_hosts` (which is the same on all hosts, as noted in the comment, and *not the list of other hosts*):

```
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.1.93:5001,192.168.1.92:5001,192.168.1.91:5001
ha.host.coordination=192.168.1.92:5001
ha.host.data=192.168.1.92:6001
```